# Can't Install Tweepy using pip on Mac OS X Terminal

Tags: python, macos, tweepy, six

I am trying to install tweepy package using "pip install tweepy" command in mac os x terminal and the installation stops in the middle giving an exception related to six python utility. It seems like tweepy is installed partially as some of the files related to it still resides in the sit-packages of python.

I have also tried reinstalling pip and tweepy using sudo commands but nothing seems to work.

//////This is the message log after this command "pip install tweepy"

DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting tweepy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/36/1b/2bd38043d22ade352fc3d3902cf30ce0e2f4bf285be3b304a2782a767aec/tweepy-3.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: PySocks>=1.5.7 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tweepy) (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tweepy) (1.2.0)
Collecting six>=1.10.0 (from tweepy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.11.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tweepy) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->tweepy) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.11.1->tweepy) (1.25.3)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.11.1->tweepy) (2019.6.16)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.11.1->tweepy) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.11.1->tweepy) (2.8)
Installing collected packages: six, tweepy
  Found existing installation: six 1.4.1

ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'six'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall

Answer (score 1):

If you are using El-Capitan then this link can fix your problem:
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3165

Try this:

pip install awsebcli --upgrade --ignore-installed six

Running on OSX El Capitan

$ eb --version

EB CLI 3.5.4 (Python 2.7.1)

Comment: Actually i was using macOS Mojave, but the problem have been solved by manually installing the tweepy package.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the root cause of the problem but found a way around and it worked:

Executed following commands on terminal:

```
git clone git://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git
cd tweepy.git
python setup.py install
```